# Running multiple spiders per one process - no output data saved

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

Please help!
Trying to create currency parser using Scrapy.
Created two spiders which works properly if run them separately.
Trying to run two spiders per one process - gives no data in output.
No matter if trying to save it to txt, json or database.

Using MySQL database.

But running one spider per one process - saves data succesfully.

The only way to save data to database or whatever - is to run `scrapy crawl Liga && scrapy crawl IFinance`.

Main spiders code:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from ..items import CurparserItem

class LigaSpider(Spider):
    name = "Liga"
    allowed_domains = ["finance.liga.net"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://finance.liga.net/currency/nbu",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        cur_list = Selector(response).xpath('//table[contains(@class, "default-table-finance course-two-col")]/tbody/tr')
        for currency in cur_list:
            item = CurparserItem()

            cur_code_raw = currency.xpath('./td[1]/a/text()').extract_first()
            item['cur_code'] = " ".join(cur_code_raw.split())
            item['cur_name'] = currency.xpath('./td[2]/text()').extract_first()
            multiple_value = currency.xpath('./td[4]/div/text()').extract_first()
            hrn_points = currency.xpath('./td[3]/text()').extract_first()
            item['cur_value'] = round(float(multiple_value)/int(hrn_points), 3)
            item['cur_behavior'] = currency.xpath('./td[4]/span/text()').extract_first()

            yield item


class IFinance(Spider):
    name = "IFinance"
    allowed_domains = ["finance.i.ua"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://finance.i.ua/nbu/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        cur_list = Selector(response).xpath('//table[contains(@class, "table-data")]/tbody/tr')
        for currency in cur_list:
            item = CurparserItem()

            item['cur_code'] = currency.xpath('./th/text()').extract_first()
            item['cur_name'] = currency.xpath('./td[2]/text()').extract_first()

            raw_behav_sign = currency.xpath('./td[3]/span/@class').extract_first()
            behav_sign = ""
            if raw_behav_sign == "value -increase":
                behav_sign = "+ "
            elif raw_behav_sign == "value -decrease":
                behav_sign = "- "
            else:
                behav_sign = ""

            item['cur_value'] = currency.xpath('./td[3]/span/span[1]/text()').extract_first()
            raw_behav_value = currency.xpath('./td[3]/span/span[2]/text()').extract_first()
            item['cur_behavior'] = behav_sign + raw_behav_value

            yield item


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(LigaSpider)
process.crawl(IFinance)
process.start()
```

Pipelines file:

````
import mysql.connector


class CurparserPipeline(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.spider.name)

    def __init__(self, spider_name):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table(spider_name)

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='3480stfgDev',
            database='currencydb'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self, spider_name):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s""" % spider_name)
        self.curr.execute("""create table %s(
                            cur_code text,
                            cur_name text,
                            cur_value float,
                            cur_behavior text
                            )""" % spider_name)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item, spider)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item, spider):
        spider_name = spider.name
        self.curr.execute("""insert into """ + spider_name + """ values (%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (
            item['cur_code'],
            item['cur_name'],
            item['cur_value'],
            item['cur_behavior']
        ))
        self.conn.commit()```
````

Comment: Does it work if you remove one of the `process.crawl()` calls? (in that case, the problem is not 1 vs 2, but `scrapy crawl` vs `process.crawl()`).

Comment: @Gallaecio Sorry for not getting quick response.
Removed `process.crawl(IFinance)` - same problem, no output.
But I mentioned some new line in logs: when I run `scrapy crawl Liga` in logs there is a line:
`2019-04-26 12:23:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['curparser.pipelines.CurparserPipeline']`
But when I run spider using `process.crawl(LigaSpider)` - the line is looks like this:
 `2019-04-26 12:22:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]` 
Can my problem be based on this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `CrawlerProcess`, project settings (i.e. from a `settings.py` file in your project folder) are not used.

See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script for information on how to pass your project settings:

```py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
```